# PHP form array value with white space

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm having a problem to pass the value of an associative array position for the value field on a form.

```
$sql = mysqli_query(
    $conn, 
    "SELECT veiculos_codvei, 
            revisao.ordemServico, 
            descricao, 
            qtd,
            precoUnt, 
            precoTotal 
       FROM revisao
      INNER JOIN itensRevisao ON revisao.ordemServico = itensRevisao.ordemServico
      WHERE codRevisao='{$codRevisao}'
    ");

    $array = array();
    // retorna consulta sql num array associativo
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }    

    print_r($array[0]['descricao'])
}
```

return "Óleo 15W40"
then I pass it to input form like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao[]" id="descricao" placeholder="Pastilha do Freio" <?php if (isset($array[0]['descricao']) and ! empty($array[0]['descricao'])) echo "value=".$array[0]['descricao']."";?>>
```

but the value of input is just "Óleo", from google chrome console I can see its the right value but seems to be a concatenation problem.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao[]" id="descricao" placeholder="Pastilha do Freio" value="Óleo" 15w40="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not have quotes around the `value` attribute (i.e you have `value=Óleo 15W40` instead of `value="Óleo 15W40"`), the quotes you see are **automaticaly added by the browser to fix the broken XML**, use the following:

```
<input 
type="text" 
class="form-control" 
name="descricao[]" 
id="descricao" 
placeholder="Pastilha do Freio"
<?php if (isset($array[0]['descricao']) and !empty($array[0]['descricao'])) echo "value=\"".$array[0]['descricao']."\"";?>
>
```

Comment: U're right, because u solved the original problem I'm voting on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, I copied this input from another part of the project and I believe there were a reason to put the value tag inside of IF, although this may be wrong anyway.
Putting  value outside the IF resolves the problem.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao[]" id="descricao" placeholder="Pastilha do Freio" value="<?php if (isset($array[0]['descricao']) and ! empty($array[0]['descricao'])) echo $array[0]['descricao'];?>">
```